# How to get the value of option element (selected from select list ) 'value' attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<select id="tournaments-name-list" style="display: block; width: 50%;">
  <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Tournaments From List</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="38299">AMANORA CA Inter Firm Cricket 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="47132">Amanora Champions Trophy 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="197831">Amanora Cricket Championship 2021</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="973">Amanora Cricket League 2017</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="79846">Amanora Cricket League Nov 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="1865">Amanora RSC 2017-18</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="109151">Amanora Super League 2020</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="31679">AMANORA SUPER LEAGUE JAN FEB 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="26011">RSC AMANORA CRICKET LEAGUE WINTER 2018</option>
</select>
```

Check the code snippet. I want to use the numeric value of the "value" attribute of the "option" element of only the selected one and also after selection is made. Then, I use it in javascript to fetch data. The select element is not a part of any form element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onchange` event of the `select` element.

```js
function handleChange(event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<select id="tournaments-name-list" style="display: block; width: 50%;" onchange="handleChange(event)">
  <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Tournaments From List</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="38299">AMANORA CA Inter Firm Cricket 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="47132">Amanora Champions Trophy 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="197831">Amanora Cricket Championship 2021</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="973">Amanora Cricket League 2017</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="79846">Amanora Cricket League Nov 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="1865">Amanora RSC 2017-18</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="109151">Amanora Super League 2020</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="31679">AMANORA SUPER LEAGUE JAN FEB 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="26011">RSC AMANORA CRICKET LEAGUE WINTER 2018</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is better - to find element by id or just pass this?

Comment: Actually, when we do the event call we get the event and the value of that one, No need to do the DOM call again! Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Finding elements is a costly operation, We are already generating an event there so just get the `value` from that one instead.

Comment: @Mehul Thakkar "when we do the event call we get the event and the value of that one" Can you explain this?

Comment: When you click on the select and change the option/element it fires `onchange` event. That event will call the handler mentioned inside `onchange`. The handler will get the event object as an argument which will be available to the handler function. 

The event object consists of many properties among which we have `target`. The `target` is precisely your select element. If you console `target` it will return the `select` DOM structure and the value will be currently selected value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change() {
  const selectValue = document.getElementById("tournaments-name-list").value;
alert(selectValue)
}
```

```html
<select id="tournaments-name-list" style="display: block; width: 50%;" onchange="change()">
  <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Tournaments From List</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="38299">AMANORA CA Inter Firm Cricket 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="47132">Amanora Champions Trophy 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="197831">Amanora Cricket Championship 2021</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="973">Amanora Cricket League 2017</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="79846">Amanora Cricket League Nov 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="1865">Amanora RSC 2017-18</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="109151">Amanora Super League 2020</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="31679">AMANORA SUPER LEAGUE JAN FEB 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="26011">RSC AMANORA CRICKET LEAGUE WINTER 2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current selected value using this:

```js
const target = window['tournaments-name-list'];
const value = target.value;
```

If you want to get the current value each time your select changes, then you can use something like this:

```js
const target = window['tournaments-name-list'];
let value = null;
const updateValue = () => {
   value = target.value;
   console.log('Your value:', value);
};
target.addEventListener('change', updateValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

in javascript pure you can do like below:

```
  var selectedValue= document.getElementById("tournaments-name-list").value
```

in jquery you can do like below as well:

```
 var selectedValue = $('#tournaments-name-list').val()
```

and now you have the selected value

if I would rewrite you code :

```
var selectedValue

function getValue(){
  selectedValue= document.getElementById("tournaments-name-list").value
}

<select id="tournaments-name-list" style="display: block; width: 50%;" onchange="getValue()">
  <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Tournaments From List</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="38299">AMANORA CA Inter Firm Cricket 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="47132">Amanora Champions Trophy 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="197831">Amanora Cricket Championship 2021</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="973">Amanora Cricket League 2017</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="79846">Amanora Cricket League Nov 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="1865">Amanora RSC 2017-18</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="109151">Amanora Super League 2020</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="31679">AMANORA SUPER LEAGUE JAN FEB 2019</option>
  <option class="tournaments-name" value="26011">RSC AMANORA CRICKET LEAGUE WINTER 2018</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this method

```
    <select id="tournaments-name-list" style="display: block; width: 50%;" onchange="getValue()">
    <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Select Tournaments From List</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="38299">AMANORA CA Inter Firm Cricket 2019</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="47132">Amanora Champions Trophy 2019</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="197831">Amanora Cricket Championship 2021</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="973">Amanora Cricket League 2017</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="79846">Amanora Cricket League Nov 2019</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="1865">Amanora RSC 2017-18</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="109151">Amanora Super League 2020</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="31679">AMANORA SUPER LEAGUE JAN FEB 2019</option>
    <option class="tournaments-name" value="26011">RSC AMANORA CRICKET LEAGUE WINTER 2018</option>
  </select>

<div id="show">
    
</div>
<script>
    function getValue() {
        var select = document.getElementById('tournaments-name-list')
        var valuee = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
        console.log(valuee)
    }
</script>
```